# Change multiples URL parameters with PushState

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, pushstate, html5-history

I need to change multiples URL parameters with pushState(),

For an example:

example.com/controller/method1/page3

If i use pushState(data, title, 'method2/page1')

It'll produce

example.com/controller/method1/method2/page1

How do I change multiples parameters to make something like this?

example.com/controller/method2/page1

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you properly, you want to make the path relative to the website's root URL?

Add a slash in front of the relative path to make it absolute and start from the root.

`'/controller/method2/page1'`

Or if you have other directories before that you can use `'../'` to indicate one level up.

`'../method2/page1'`

Comment: You can upvote my answer to help others find this answer faster haha. cheers.